# Logging practice for frequently called methods

Tags: java, logging, exception

In game development many methods are called very often (e.g. 60 times per second). Sometimes I'd like to log catched exceptions even in such methods but not that often.

My idea was to only log the first occurrence of an exception that occurend in a specific method but I did not find any convenient or build-in solution to do that (at least in java).

Comment: Why don't you just create a flag? If it's true, you log and set to false.

Comment: Thanks, yes this would do the trick but I hoped for a solution where this logic is encapsulated in the logger and not in my application.

Comment: In general that kind of logic wouldn't be handled in the logger, but a logging adapter. E.g., if you're logging events you'd probably want to shove the responsibility of *persisting* the log msg to something not on a critical code path. Once you've done that the idea of throttling or aggregating becomes a lot easier.

Comment: To me, the name "exception" implies that it is rare. Having something rare happening 60 times a second seems off to me. Maybe you want to think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using a specific logger that supports this feature, the behavior you're trying to get can be acheived through a flag system.

For example, you could add in your logging class a map like this:

```
Map<Class, MyTimer> logged = new HashMap<>();
```

And in your logging function (let's say `log(Object objectToLog)`):

```
if (objectToLog instanceof Exception) {
    MyTimer t = logged.get(objectToLog.class);
    if (t == null || t.getDifferenceTimeWithNow() > MYLOG.DELAY ) {
        log(objectToLog);
        logged.put(objectToLog.class, t.setToNow());
    }
    else {
        t.setToNow();
    }
}
```

This way, the only call you have to do sixty times a second is a simple `Map#get`, an `if` comparaison and a `MyTimer#setToNow`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in my home-made game project I decided to log only "new" messages. I used following approach:

1. Detect log-method call "location".
2. If the message from this location has changed from the last time then log it, ignore otherwise.

I can't show you my actual code, as it was not on Java and used macros, but with `log4j` `Filter`s it can be achieved like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo;

public class DuplicateMessagesFilter extends Filter {
  Map<String,String> previousMessages = new HashMap<String,String>();

  @Override
  public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
      LocationInfo locationInfo = event.getLocationInformation();
      String location = locationInfo.getFileName() + ":" + locationInfo.getLineNumber();
      String previousMessage = previousMessages.get(location);
      if(previousMessage != null && previousMessage.equals(event.getMessage())){
        return DENY;
      }

      previousMessages.put(location, event.getMessage());
      return ACCEPT;
  }
}
```